# How to check whether a file is a macOS executable from Python?

Tags: python, macos

For example, given:

```sh
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS
$ file Xcode
Xcode: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

and:

```sh
$ cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A
$ file IDEKit
IDEKit: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

I want to be able to do what `file` is doing, specifically to check whether a file is an executable or not, but programmatically from Python.

I know I *could* invoke the `file` command and parse the result from Python, but is there a better way that doesn't involve invoking `file`?

Note that:

```sh
$ ls -l IDEKit
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 17256912 Apr  5 17:42 IDEKit*
```

and:

```sh
$ ls -l Xcode
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  44416 Apr 11 13:40 Xcode*
```

i.e., they are both "executable" as far as filesystem permissions bits are concerned, but only `Xcode` is a true executable.

Comment: One way would be to read a files magic number and compare it to a list such as this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures. Or just look at `file`'s source code and see how it does it.

Comment: @Perplexabot magic number is the same for Mach-O 64-bit executable & dylib. This is a good answer that goes deeper https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057382/5329717 , not Python though.

Comment: @Kamil.S , interesting, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the [macholib](https://macholib.readthedocs.io/) allows you to read and inspect the Mach-O headers of a file (if it has them) from Python.  So code like:

```
def read_macho_headers( file ):
    try:
        return MachO.MachO( file ).headers
    except Exception:                   # not a Mach-O file
        return None

def is_macho_exe( macho_headers ):
    filetype = macho_headers[0].header.filetype
    return filetype == mach_o.MH_EXECUTE
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`file-magic`](https://pypi.org/project/file-magic/) which is the official python bindings for `file`.

Once installed, you can just inspect files.

```py
import magic

detected = magic.detect_from_filename('magic.py')
print 'Detected MIME type: {}'.format(detected.mime_type)
print 'Detected encoding: {}'.format(detected.encoding)
print 'Detected file type name: {}'.format(detected.name)
```